# Handling user relationship with LDAP authentication

Tags: database, orm, ldap

I'm setting up a web app with LDAP authentication and I'm not too sure how to handle user db relationships (e.g. created by, assigned to, approvers, members)

So far, I came up with the following options:

1. when the user first log's in, check if a record exists in a users
   table. If not, perform an ldap lookup to retrieve name and email and
   create a user record. Same thing would happen when a user is added
   to a list or selected. (possibly storing last ldap lookup date and
   refreshing detail on login after x days)
2. create a user record with just the cn, and perform on-the-fly lookups for name and email
3. just store the cn instead of fk, and perform on-the-fly lookups for name and email.

I'm inclined to go for option 1 as it would keep things simple for ORM and reduces the number of lookups..on the other hand it seems a little over-engineered.

Any alternatives or reasons why the above options should be avoided, would be appreciated.

Comment: You should be putting the roles into LDAP, not a separate database. That's what LDAP is for.

Comment: this is not about roles..

Comment: Approvers and members are both roles.

Comment: not if the teams are maintained by users and approver is selected by the user ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably depends on your use-case.

- Do you want to know about all the users (even those who have not yet logged in)?
- Do you need to store custom attributes for them?
- Do you need to make relational queries based on user attributes?

Just a few comparisons:

- [Linux PAM](http://linux.die.net/man/5/pam_ldap) uses the option 3 (NSS).
- [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com) or [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) both use modified option 1.

In fact, the majority of applications I've seen are using modified option 1. It is because LDAP is usually just one of supported **authentication** options and in many cases you want to store additional data for every user and work with the entry as with any other entity (speaking of relations, memberships, ...). The important difference from your description is:

- Refresh user entry every time the user logs in.

Note that there is a fourth possibility - don't integrate with LDAP directly and let [IdM system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_management_system) provision users to your application. However this requires a working IdM to be present in your target environment.

Comment: thanks for the info, I think i'll go for option 1 with refresh on login and using a shared user database for all systems that will use this mechanism.

There are no plans to store custom attributes, but queries on user attributes are important. There will be cases when I need the details of users that have not logged in yet, but I can cater for that easily.